# ScrollEventType.ThumbPosition Not Working in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, scrollbar

In my C# Windows Form Application, I have a `DataGridView` control with both `Horizontal and Vertical Scrollbars`. The scrollbars showed up because the table size is huge and the space for the `DataGridView` is too small to show all the data at once.

Now, I want to raise a scroll event when the user is moving the scrollbar horizontally, and also when they stop moving the scrollbar. For simplification purpose, I want to change a panel's color depending on whether the horizontal scrollbar is in motion (Green) or not (Red). By default, it is red.

I have the following code, but it is not working. Can someone tell me why this is not working?

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    MyPanel.BackColor = Color.Red; //Default panel color
    MyDGV.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(MyDGV_Scroll); //Subscribe to the event
}

private void MyDGV_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e){
    //If the horizontal scrollbar is moving
    if(e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll){
        //While the scrollbox is getting moved
        if(e.Type == ScrollEventType.ThumbPosition){
             myPanel.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else{  //The user stopped moving the scrollbar
             myPanel.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

When I checked the code flow with breakpoints, I noticed that it passes the first *if statement*, but the second one fails and it always go to the *else statement* even if the scrollbar is getting moved.

Why is this not working?

Comment: It is hard to debug because as soon as the breakpoint hits you can no longer scroll.  Use Debug.Print() instead and you'll see that you just can't get the notification you want.  Consider using a Timer to reset the color.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to stop the Timer while the scrollbar is in motion and resume when the scrollbar stops moving.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense.  Call Timer.Stop() *and* Timer.Start() in your Scroll event handler.  When it ticks you know you haven't seen a scroll event for a while.  So call Timer.Stop() and change the color.

Comment: I wanted to stop the timer while scrolling because when the `Timer` refresh occurs to the `DataGridView`s data while scrolling, it detach the mouse dragging from the scrollbar. Like it interrupts the scrolling. I want to prevent this.